# Remove Country as mandatary field when calculating shipping price in cart page

Tags: cart, shipping-methods

if we go for cart page, we can see an option to find shipping charges by entering zip code....

[image]

here we set default country as "India", but still when we entered zip code and click on

"Get a Quote" **still its asking to select country**.

i want to remove this restriction.

we are using following code :

```
 <label for="country" ><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Country') ?></label>
<div class="input-box">
<?php echo Mage::getBlockSingleton('directory/data')->getCountryHtmlSelect($this->getEstimateCountryId()) ?>
</div>
```

This is complete code of the file

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/cart/shipping.phtml




<?php
/**
 * Magento
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE_AFL.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@magentocommerce.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
 * versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
 * needs please refer to http://www.magentocommerce.com for more information.
 *
 * @category    design
 * @package     base_default
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2014 Magento Inc. (http://www.magentocommerce.com)
 * @license     http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php  Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
 */
?>
<?php /** @var $this Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart_Shipping */ ?>
<div class="shipping">
    <h2><?php echo $this->__('Estimate Shipping and Tax') ?></h2>
    <div class="shipping-form">
       <form action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/cart/estimatePost') ?>" method="post" id="shipping-zip-form">
            <p><?php echo $this->__('Enter your destination to get a shipping estimate.') ?></p>
            <ul class="form-list">
                <li>
                    <label for="country" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Country') ?></label>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <?php echo Mage::getBlockSingleton('directory/data')->getCountryHtmlSelect($this->getEstimateCountryId()) ?>
                    </div>
                </li>
            <?php //if($this->getStateActive()): ?>
                <li>
                    <label for="region_id"<?php if ($this->isStateProvinceRequired()) echo ' class="required"' ?>><?php if ($this->isStateProvinceRequired()) echo '<em>*</em>' ?><?php echo $this->__('State/Province') ?></label>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <select id="region_id" name="region_id" title="<?php echo $this->__('State/Province') ?>" style="display:none;"<?php echo ($this->isStateProvinceRequired() ? ' class="validate-select"' : '') ?>>
                            <option value=""><?php echo $this->__('Please select region, state or province') ?></option>
                        </select>
                       <script type="text/javascript">
                       //<![CDATA[
                           $('region_id').setAttribute('defaultValue',  "<?php echo $this->getEstimateRegionId() ?>");
                       //]]>
                       </script>
                       <input type="text" id="region" name="region" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getEstimateRegion()) ?>"  title="<?php echo $this->__('State/Province') ?>" class="input-text" style="display:none;" />
                   </div>
                </li>
            <?php //endif; ?>
            <?php if($this->getCityActive()): ?>
                <li>
                    <label for="city"<?php if ($this->isCityRequired()) echo ' class="required"' ?>><?php if ($this->isCityRequired()) echo '<em>*</em>' ?><?php echo $this->__('City') ?></label>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <input class="input-text<?php if ($this->isCityRequired()):?> required-entry<?php endif;?>" id="city" type="text" name="estimate_city" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getEstimateCity()) ?>" />
                    </div>
                </li>
            <?php endif; ?>
                <li>
                    <label for="postcode"<?php if ($this->isZipCodeRequired()) echo ' class="required"' ?>><?php if ($this->isZipCodeRequired()) echo '<em>*</em>' ?><?php echo $this->__('Zip/Postal Code') ?></label>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <input class="input-text validate-postcode<?php if ($this->isZipCodeRequired()):?> required-entry<?php endif;?>" type="text" id="postcode" name="estimate_postcode" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getEstimatePostcode()) ?>" />
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="buttons-set">
                <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Get a Quote') ?>" onclick="coShippingMethodForm.submit()" class="button"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Get a Quote') ?></span></span></button>
            </div>
        </form>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[
            new RegionUpdater('country', 'region', 'region_id', <?php echo $this->helper('directory')->getRegionJson() ?>);
        //]]>
        </script>

        <?php if (($_shippingRateGroups = $this->getEstimateRates())): ?>
        <form id="co-shipping-method-form" action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/cart/estimateUpdatePost') ?>">
            <dl class="sp-methods">
                <?php foreach ($_shippingRateGroups as $code => $_rates): ?>
                    <dt><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getCarrierName($code)) ?></dt>
                    <dd>
                        <ul>
                        <?php foreach ($_rates as $_rate): ?>
                            <li<?php if ($_rate->getErrorMessage()) echo ' class="error-msg"';?>>
                               <?php if ($_rate->getErrorMessage()): ?>
                                    <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_rate->getErrorMessage()) ?>
                               <?php else: ?>
                                    <input name="estimate_method" type="radio" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_rate->getCode()) ?>" id="s_method_<?php echo $_rate->getCode() ?>"<?php if($_rate->getCode()===$this->getAddressShippingMethod()) echo ' checked="checked"' ?> class="radio" />
                                    <label for="s_method_<?php echo $_rate->getCode() ?>"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_rate->getMethodTitle()) ?>
                                    <?php $_excl = $this->getShippingPrice($_rate->getPrice(), $this->helper('tax')->displayShippingPriceIncludingTax()); ?>
                                    <?php $_incl = $this->getShippingPrice($_rate->getPrice(), true); ?>
                                    <?php echo $_excl; ?>
                                    <?php if ($this->helper('tax')->displayShippingBothPrices() && $_incl != $_excl): ?>
                                        (<?php echo $this->__('Incl. Tax'); ?> <?php echo $_incl; ?>)
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                    </label>
                               <?php endif ?>
                            </li>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                        </ul>
                    </dd>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </dl>
            <div class="buttons-set">
                <button type="submit" title="<?php echo $this->__('Update Total') ?>" class="button" name="do" value="<?php echo $this->__('Update Total') ?>"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Update Total') ?></span></span></button>
            </div>
        </form>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[
            var coShippingMethodForm = new VarienForm('shipping-zip-form');
            var countriesWithOptionalZip = <?php echo $this->helper('directory')->getCountriesWithOptionalZip(true) ?>;

            coShippingMethodForm.submit = function () {
                var country = $F('country');
                var optionalZip = false;

                for (i=0; i < countriesWithOptionalZip.length; i++) {
                    if (countriesWithOptionalZip[i] == country) {
                        optionalZip = true;
                    }
                }
                if (optionalZip) {
                    $('postcode').removeClassName('required-entry');
                }
                else {
                    $('postcode').addClassName('required-entry');
                }
                return VarienForm.prototype.submit.bind(coShippingMethodForm)();
            }
        //]]>
        </script>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can rewrite the method `Mage_Directory_Block_Data::getCountryHtmlSelect` and remove this line `->setClass('validate-select')`.

Or you can add a simple js code in your template that removes the class `validate-select`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.observe("dom:loaded", function() {
        $('country_id').removeClassName('validate-select');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: i added JS code at the end of the shipping.phtml file, but still its asking to select "country" .

Comment: not sure about this, but you can also try to remove the class `required-entry`.

Comment: sorry, did't worked for me.

Comment: i removed `required` here : `<li>
                    <label for="country" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Country') ?></label>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <?php echo Mage::getBlockSingleton('directory/data')->getCountryHtmlSelect($this->getEstimateCountryId()) ?>
                    </div>
                </li>`

Comment: Fantastic boss, i asked one question, you gave solution in 3 ways - php, js & css..... This is what ultimate answer....